# Metastorm BPM 6.x where does the to-do list information comes from?

Tags: workflow

I had a brunch of sales data for may wrong and duplicating so I deleted the whole thing form the db eFolder and precedents tables from my process.

What I don't understand is that although they're not on the database any more they still appear on the front end!

Where does that list come from? Does anyone know?

Answer (score 0):

The lists that you seeare comming from the eAlert table.  These records allocate eFolder records to specific users so it's likely that you need to delete these too.

```
DELETE eAlert WHERE eFolderId NOT IN (SELECT eFolderId FROM eFolder)
```